# linux- env variables getting reset after closing the console

Tags: bash, environment-variables

The `env` variables I set are getting reset to the previous values after closing the current instance of the `bash` console. How to set or unset those variables without getting them reset everytime? I am using OpenSuse 12.3 with bash 4.2

Comment: Using `export` to set variables?

Comment: yes using `export`

Comment: @SlightlyCuban: `export` makes environment variables available to child processes. It has nothing to do with persistence and will not help this problem.

Comment: @garyjohn thanks for clarifying. what do i do for persistence?

Comment: It depends on the distribution, whether you want them visible to programs launched from your window manager, and whether you want them visible to all users or just you. The usual place for just you is ~/.profile, or if you're using bash, ~/.bash_profile. If they only need to be seen by interactive shells and their children, ~/.bashrc will do. To been seen by all users, use /etc/environment, /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc, depending on their scope, your distribution and your shell.

Answer (score 2):

`export` only sets variables for that shell. To make it available to all shells, you'll need to add the variables to `~/.bashrc` (for your user account) or to `/etc/bashrc` (for all accounts on the system): https://marylou.byu.edu/documentation/unix-tutorial/unix9.php

These configuration scripts are called when you first start bash, so any environment variables you define in there would be defined for all shells.